# If it's possible to get something from '(.*)' into a variable?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I'm only learning cucumber.Tell me if it's possible to get something from '(.*)' into a variable?

```
@Then("^ Page is '(.*)' on PDP$")
```

For example : @Then("^ Page is 'display' on PDP$").And I want to get the word 'display'  in a variable. Because i want work with it in my method.

I want something like this

```
@Then("^ Page is '(.*)' on PDP$")
public void title() {
    String str = '(.*)';  
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual step from a scenario. The regular expression in Java is only half the story.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a cucumber and write some description in a step, you can select the desired word and receive it in the method arguments.

```
@Then("^ Page is '(.*)' on PDP$")
public void title(String str) {
    String str = '(.*)';  
    ...
}
```